# OLS with both panel-corrected standard errors and AR(1) correction in R

Tags: r

I am looking to replicate the following Stata command in R:

```
xtpcse   y  x1   x2  x3  x4  i.xfe, corr(ar1) pairwise
```

where i.xfe is a fixed-effects factor.

I have typically used `plm` with the `coeftest` function (with `vcovBK`) for running regressions with panel-corrected standard errors. But it does not appear, unless I am mistaken, that an AR1 correlation structure can be incorporated into a `plm` regression.

I believe I can use the `gls` function in the `nlme` package to incorporate an AR1 structure:

```
gls(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + factor(xfe),
                      data = data,
                      correlation = corAR1(form=~1),
                      na.action = na.omit)
```

but I have not been able to find a way of then calculating PCSEs. `vcovBK` does not appear to accept `gls`-type objects.

How can both PCSEs and an AR1 correction be incorporated into a model in R? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The method you want to use is the Praise-Winsten regression for panel data.

The panelAR package in R can be used to do this. I have given an example of stata code and its equivalent for R.
Stata code:

```
xtpcse depvar indepvar, correlation(psar1)
```

Rcode:

```
require(panelAR)
panelAR(formula = formula ,data = data, panelVar = 'N', timeVar = 'T',
 panelCorrMethod = "pcse", autoCorr = "psar1", complete.case = T)
```